# Is this really the way to pass void functions to Scala methods from Java?

Tags: java, scala, lambda, scala-java-interop

I've been playing with Scala/Java interop lately, specifically, calling *Scala* (2.10.4) code from *Java* (7).  It's been more pleasant than I expected, but a few things puzzle me.

E.g., in `scala.runtime` I have a nice collection of `AbstractFunction` abstract classes.  But I don't see anything for methods with no return value.  E.g., suppose I have the following Scala code:

```
class MyClass(name: String) {
  def SayWhat(say_fn: String => Unit) = say_fn(name)
}
```

My understanding is that Java's `void` is more or less Scala's `Unit`, so I can pass something vaguely lambda-like with the following Java anonymous class:

```
import scala.Function1;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;
import scala.runtime.BoxedUnit;

public class MyProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass("Dan");

    Function1<String, BoxedUnit> f = new AbstractFunction1<String, BoxedUnit>() {
      public BoxedUnit apply(String s) {
        System.out.println("Why, hello there " + s);
          return null;
      }
    };

    mc.SayWhat(f);
  }
}
```

This obviously not the prettiest thing, but I appreciate the `AbstractFunction` stuff, really, compared to what I would have to do otherwise!  But is there really no `AbstractProcedure` or something?  Also, why does my "lambda" have to return `BoxedUnit`?

Comment: You could add an `AbstractProcedure` object with the function `def apply[T](f:T=>_):T=>Unit = x =>f(x)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function actually has to return `BoxedUnit.UNIT`, which is the unit in question.

`Unit` is an `AnyVal`, not an `AnyRef`, so it doesn't include null.

It is so much nicer when functions return interesting values.